# The Use of AI and Machine Learning in Organic Chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemical-engineering, machine-learning

I am trying to do a bit of research into the current use of machine learning in chemical industry. I've been told my original question was too general so I'll try to be more specific about what I'm interested in.

I've read several articles about the computational techniques used for retrosynthesis, where a desired molecule is set as an input and the output being a series of feasible chemical reactions beginning with easily sourced/purchasable materials.

I'd like to know if/where techniques like this are being used in industry with any frequency or is it something still in the early stages of development and sees little to no practical application.

Comment: It is an open ended question, please make it more specific. One application, which has interested me a lot is the ability of machine translation of scientific chemistry texts. Chemical structures, mathematical equations create a lot of problems. A lot of useful and historical information of organic chemistry is in German and French. Search the Journal of Chemical Information and Modelling for such topics.

Comment: I have heard that retrosynthesis was also developed for the computers to suggest synthetic routes.

Comment: @M.Farooq Learn German, or French? You need but a basic understanding of the languages before you can read chemical texts just like that. Poetry and politics are a lot harder. ;)

Comment: @Karl, I was talking about machine translation of scientific texts. Both Google Translate and DeepL do a great job provided you follow some good practices and perhaps some "rules. I have published two survey articles on that topic. Since you already speak German, you may not worry about it :-)

Comment: @M.Farooq I have found I can also read Spanish OC chemistry (learned French at school?), and Swedish (finished half an A1 course). It's just extremely simple. ;-) Compared to the newspaper, where I get what it's all about, but would fail miserably in a basic reading comprehension test.

Comment: The question is1)  too broad, 2) essentially asking for references (which is not the goal of this site). For this question an answer about using google for research is a correct answer. If you formulate the question better, you get better answers. One way is getting more specific about what have you found so far, and where you are missing there. Have you read any reviews? How old results are you interested in (see chemoinformatics as a field)? Also, please note that AI is often just a marketing term, used vaguely.

Comment: Well, this seems to be the question you are asking: [What is the current status of machine learning applied to materials or molecular systems?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/18/49)

Comment: In addition to «it is an open end question», (retro)synthetical planning by a computer is a field with long tradition (e.g., LHASA around the Corey group, see for example Derek Lowe's pipeline, https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2018/03/06/retrosynthesis-here-it-comes). For more recent examples, see the 2020 RDKit UGM, esp. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyHVwJUBDIk&list=PLugOo5eIVY3HW8kJYnoBNyJvg8P6qtl44&index=13, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ntPCu-rp_k&list=PLugOo5eIVY3HW8kJYnoBNyJvg8P6qtl44&index=21).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a) there is too little evidence the OP took a moment to browse briefly the pages of publishers (example [ACS](https://pubs.acs.org/action/doSearch?AllField=Machine+Learning+for+Drug+Discovery)).  And b), in its current state, the question appears to attract answers which are self-promotion (twice an answer pointing to a book by James Bonnar hosted by an unknown source).